# Seeking park land cover in UK?

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I would like to mapping like in this link 
http://www.geocomputation.org/1998/78/gc78_07.jpg

However, I could not find the park data, so do anyone know where can I find these kind of data.

Comment: Do you want free data, if so it might be better asking on [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Possibly look at https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/about/news/2017/os-releases-open-dataset-free-map-gb-greenspaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The park data seems to be from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/51.4852/-3.1433) licensed under the [Open Data Commons Open Database License (ODbL)](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/en).

You can use Overpass Turbo [with this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/quq) to extract all parks in Cardiff and use them in your GIS application.